# cakePHP is escaping field names, as strings, in BETWEEN condition

Tags: php, mysql, find, cakephp-1.3, between

Cake is escaping the `Contract.start_date` and `Contract.end_date`, rendering the query useless.

```
$this -> Contract -> find('all', array(
  'fields' => array(..),
  'conditions' => array(
     'NOW() BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array(
        'Contract.start_date',
        'Contract.end_date'
      )
   )
));
```

The problem is that the query that is executed is

```
SELECT
  <fields> AS Monthly 
FROM 
  `contracts` AS `Contract` 
WHERE
  NOW() BETWEEN 'Contract.start_date' AND 'Contract.end_date' 
#/* field names are escaped and treated as strings */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because query parameterization is for values (parameters), not fields. You can't use the ? tokens to replace field names because, as you've discovered, they're quoted as if they were string values. (The same holds true for database and table names as well, which is how I've run up against this before and therefore know the answer to your problem now, too.)

In this case, you want to simply use `'NOW() BETWEEN Contract.start_date AND Contract.end_date'`.